# Magento 2 Static Content deploy requried?

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I am a newbie in Magento2 I read some articles in which they mention like in Developer mode there is no need for Content deploy, it is only required in production mode.

but when I worked practically I faced an issue for this, without static content deploy my code was not updating, so I want to know what is Magento doing while Static content deploy.

any reference links would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**This is the command you had run before deploying to production mode. If you're running in default or developer mode, those files should be generating for your automatically.** If you accidentally removed a folder Magento expects to be there -- running setup:static-content:deploy may restore that folder, or may result in an explicit error about the missing folders.

If you need more details about content deploy you can try this code to get more information about this.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -h

Output will be :

```
Usage:
  setup:static-content:deploy [options] [--] [<languages>]...

Arguments:
  languages                                  Space-separated list of ISO-636 language codes for which to output static view files.

Options:
  -f, --force                                Deploy files in any mode.
  -s, --strategy[=STRATEGY]                  Deploy files using specified strategy. [default: "quick"]
  -a, --area[=AREA]                          Generate files only for the specified areas. [default: ["all"]] (multiple values allowed)
      --exclude-area[=EXCLUDE-AREA]          Do not generate files for the specified areas. [default: ["none"]] (multiple values allowed)
  -t, --theme[=THEME]                        Generate static view files for only the specified themes. [default: ["all"]] (multiple values allowed)
      --exclude-theme[=EXCLUDE-THEME]        Do not generate files for the specified themes. [default: ["none"]] (multiple values allowed)
  -l, --language[=LANGUAGE]                  Generate files only for the specified languages. [default: ["all"]] (multiple values allowed)
      --exclude-language[=EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]  Do not generate files for the specified languages. [default: ["none"]] (multiple values allowed)
  -j, --jobs[=JOBS]                          Enable parallel processing using the specified number of jobs. [default: 0]
      --symlink-locale                       Create symlinks for the files of those locales, which are passed for deployment, but have no customizations.
      --content-version=CONTENT-VERSION      Custom version of static content can be used if running deployment on multiple nodes to ensure that static content version is identical and caching works properly.
      --refresh-content-version-only         Refreshing the version of static content only can be used to refresh static content in browser cache and CDN cache.
      --no-javascript                        Do not deploy JavaScript files.
      --no-css                               Do not deploy CSS files.
      --no-less                              Do not deploy LESS files.
      --no-images                            Do not deploy images.
      --no-fonts                             Do not deploy font files.
      --no-html                              Do not deploy HTML files.
      --no-misc                              Do not deploy files of other types (.md, .jbf, .csv, etc.).
      --no-html-minify                       Do not minify HTML files.
  -h, --help                                 Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                                Do not output any message
  -V, --version                              Display this application version
      --ansi                                 Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                              Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction                       Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose                       Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Help:
  Deploys static view files
```

Let me know if you need more information about static deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.